# How to find a photo saved from iMessage

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

A friend send me a photo through iMessage and I saved it. However, the photo was from the past, so when I look at my photo album (of which there are thousands of photos that are sorted by time) I cannot find it (it's hidden among the thousands of photos).

**How can I find the photo I just saved?**

(In case you're curious why I want to find it, I want to add a caption to it and add it to a particular (non-shared) album. If there are ways of doing this that don't require finding it, hearing those in the comments would be great, but they won't answer the main question.)

Comment: Only you know _what_ the photo contained, and only you know _when_ the photo was delivered. I'm not sure how we can help. You might want to take a look at [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer), which can export an entire iMessage thread from a specific correspondent into a single PDF file, which may be more visually 'searchable'. _Disclaimer: satisfied user of iExplorer. No financial or other connection to Macroplant LLC._

Comment: I don't know when the photo was originally taken, which I believe it how Photos sorts the images. Even if I could find out when the photo was originally taken, that would be enough to locate it (I can handle scrolling through a day's worth of photos). Do you know how to find when a photo was originally taken, given a photo sent through Messages?